# How to properly build a music service that never stops when app quits, with lock screen media controls?

Tags: java, android, android-service, android-mediaplayer

I tried this several times with no success.

1. Service stops when quieting the app, or even when pressing the back button.

I want the music to continue even when the app is swiped up, just like Google music.

2. I set the session and media controls, but when device is locked, there's no way to control music playback.

What might I be missing? The following are the classes for this.

**MusicService**

```
public class MediaPlayerService extends Service implements 
MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener, MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener,

MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener, MediaPlayer.OnSeekCompleteListener,

MediaPlayer.OnInfoListener, MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener,

AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener {
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    private final IBinder iBinder = new LocalBinder();

    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    initMediaPlayer();
    callStateListener();
    registerBecomingNoisyReceiver();
    register_playNewAudio();
}

public static final String MusicServiceTag = "MusicTest";

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    try {
        StorageUtil storage = new StorageUtil(getApplicationContext());
        audioList = storage.loadAudio();
        audioIndex = storage.loadAudioIndex();
        if (audioIndex != -1 && audioIndex < audioList.size()) {
            activeAudio = audioList.get(audioIndex);
        } else {
            stopSelf();
        }
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        stopSelf();
    }

    //Request audio focus
    if (!requestAudioFocus()) {
        //Could not gain focus
        stopSelf();
    }

    if (mediaSessionManager == null) {
        try {
            initMediaSession();
            initMediaPlayer();
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            stopSelf();
        }
        buildNotification(PlaybackStatus.PLAYING);
    }

    //Handle Intent action from MediaSession.TransportControls
    handleIncomingActions(intent);
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mediaPlayer != null) {
        stopMedia();
        mediaPlayer.release();
    }
    removeAudioFocus();
    //Disable the PhoneStateListener
    if (phoneStateListener != null) {
        telephonyManager.listen(phoneStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE);
    }

    removeNotification();

    //unregister BroadcastReceivers
    unregisterReceiver(becomingNoisyReceiver);
    unregisterReceiver(playNewAudio);

    //clear cached playlist
    new StorageUtil(getApplicationContext()).clearCachedAudioPlaylist();
}

private int resumePosition;

private void initMediaPlayer() {
    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
    mediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(this);
    mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
    mediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
    mediaPlayer.setOnSeekCompleteListener(this);
    mediaPlayer.setOnInfoListener(this);
    mediaPlayer.reset();
    mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    try {
        System.out.println(MusicServiceTag + "File :: " + activeAudio);
        String x = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6c/Grieg_Lyric_Pieces_Kobold.ogg";
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(activeAudio == null ? x : activeAudio.getData());
        mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        stopSelf();
    }
}

private void playMedia() {
    if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }
}

private void stopMedia() {
    if (mediaPlayer == null) return;
    if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        mediaPlayer.stop();
    }
}

private void pauseMedia() {
    if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        mediaPlayer.pause();
        resumePosition = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
    }
}

private void resumeMedia() {
    if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        mediaPlayer.seekTo(resumePosition);
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }
}

@Override
public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer, int i) {

}

@Override
public boolean onInfo(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer, int i, int i1) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onSeekComplete(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {

}

public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
    public MediaPlayerService getService() {
        return MediaPlayerService.this;
    }
}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return iBinder;
}

@Override
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
    stopMedia();
    stopSelf();
}

private static final String TAG_ERROR = "MediaPlayer Error";


@Override
public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
    switch (what) {
        case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_NOT_VALID_FOR_PROGRESSIVE_PLAYBACK:
            Log.d(TAG_ERROR, "MEDIA ERROR NOT VALID FOR PROGRESSIVE PLAYBACK " + extra);
            break;
        case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_SERVER_DIED:
            Log.d(TAG_ERROR, "MEDIA ERROR SERVER DIED " + extra);
            break;
        case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_UNKNOWN:
            Log.d(TAG_ERROR, "MEDIA ERROR UNKNOWN " + extra);
            break;
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
    playMedia();
}

//Audio Focus

private AudioManager audioManager;

//List of available Audio files
private ArrayList<Sound> audioList;
private int audioIndex = -1;
private Sound activeAudio; //an object of the currently playing audio

@Override
public void onAudioFocusChange(int focusState) {
    //Invoked when the audio focus of the system is updated.
    switch (focusState) {
        case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN:
            // resume playback
            if (mediaPlayer == null) initMediaPlayer();
            else if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) mediaPlayer.start();
            mediaPlayer.setVolume(1.0f, 1.0f);
            break;
        case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS:
            // Lost focus for an unbounded amount of time: stop playback and release media player
            if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) mediaPlayer.stop();
            mediaPlayer.release();
            mediaPlayer = null;
            break;
        case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT:
            // Lost focus for a short time, but we have to stop
            // playback. We don't release the media player because playback
            // is likely to resume
            if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) mediaPlayer.pause();
            break;
        case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT_CAN_DUCK:
            // Lost focus for a short time, but it's ok to keep playing
            // at an attenuated level
            if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) mediaPlayer.setVolume(0.1f, 0.1f);
            break;
    }
}

private boolean requestAudioFocus() {
    audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    int result = audioManager.requestAudioFocus(this, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN);
    return result == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED;
}

private boolean removeAudioFocus() {
    return AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED ==
           audioManager.abandonAudioFocus(this);
}

//Becoming noisy
private BroadcastReceiver becomingNoisyReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //pause audio on ACTION_AUDIO_BECOMING_NOISY
        pauseMedia();
        buildNotification(PlaybackStatus.PAUSED);
    }
};

private void registerBecomingNoisyReceiver() {
    //register after getting audio focus
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(AudioManager.ACTION_AUDIO_BECOMING_NOISY);
    registerReceiver(becomingNoisyReceiver, intentFilter);
}

//Handle incoming phone calls
private boolean ongoingCall = false;
private PhoneStateListener phoneStateListener;
private TelephonyManager   telephonyManager;

//Handle incoming phone calls
private void callStateListener() {
    // Get the telephony manager
    telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    //Starting listening for PhoneState changes
    phoneStateListener = new PhoneStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
            switch (state) {
                //if at least one call exists or the phone is ringing
                //pause the MediaPlayer
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                    if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                        pauseMedia();
                        ongoingCall = true;
                    }
                    break;
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                    // Phone idle. Start playing.
                    if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                        if (ongoingCall) {
                            ongoingCall = false;
                            resumeMedia();
                        }
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    };
    // Register the listener with the telephony manager
    // Listen for changes to the device call state.
    telephonyManager.listen(phoneStateListener,
            PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
}

private BroadcastReceiver playNewAudio = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        //Get the new media index form SharedPreferences
        audioIndex = new StorageUtil(getApplicationContext()).loadAudioIndex();
        if (audioIndex != -1 && audioIndex < audioList.size()) {
            //index is in a valid range
            activeAudio = audioList.get(audioIndex);
        } else {
            stopSelf();
        }

        //A PLAY_NEW_AUDIO action received
        //reset mediaPlayer to play the new Audio
        stopMedia();
        mediaPlayer.reset();
        initMediaPlayer();
        updateMetaData();
        buildNotification(PlaybackStatus.PLAYING);
    }
};

private void register_playNewAudio() {
    //Register playNewMedia receiver
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(MainActivity.Broadcast_PLAY_NEW_AUDIO);
    registerReceiver(playNewAudio, filter);
}

//Notifications

public static final String ACTION_PLAY     = "com.valdioveliu.valdio.audioplayer.ACTION_PLAY";
public static final String ACTION_PAUSE    = "com.valdioveliu.valdio.audioplayer.ACTION_PAUSE";
public static final String ACTION_PREVIOUS = "com.valdioveliu.valdio.audioplayer.ACTION_PREVIOUS";
public static final String ACTION_NEXT     = "com.valdioveliu.valdio.audioplayer.ACTION_NEXT";
public static final String ACTION_STOP     = "com.valdioveliu.valdio.audioplayer.ACTION_STOP";

//MediaSession
private MediaSessionManager                     mediaSessionManager;
private MediaSessionCompat                      mediaSession;
private MediaControllerCompat.TransportControls transportControls;

//AudioPlayer notification ID
private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 101;

private void initMediaSession() throws RemoteException {
    if (mediaSessionManager != null) {
        return; //mediaSessionManager exists
    }

    mediaSessionManager = (MediaSessionManager) getSystemService(Context.MEDIA_SESSION_SERVICE);
    // Create a new MediaSession
    mediaSession = new MediaSessionCompat(getApplicationContext(), "AudioPlayer");
    //Get MediaSessions transport controls
    transportControls = mediaSession.getController().getTransportControls();
    //set MediaSession -> ready to receive media commands
    mediaSession.setActive(true);
    //indicate that the MediaSession handles transport control commands
    // through its MediaSessionCompat.Callback.
    mediaSession.setFlags(MediaSessionCompat.FLAG_HANDLES_TRANSPORT_CONTROLS);

    //Set mediaSession's MetaData
    updateMetaData();

    // Attach Callback to receive MediaSession updates
    mediaSession.setCallback(new MediaSessionCompat.Callback() {
        // Implement callbacks
        @Override
        public void onPlay() {
            super.onPlay();
            resumeMedia();
            buildNotification(PlaybackStatus.PLAYING);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPause() {
            super.onPause();
            pauseMedia();
            buildNotification(PlaybackStatus.PAUSED);
        }

        @Override
        public void onSkipToNext() {
            super.onSkipToNext();
            skipToNext();
            updateMetaData();
            buildNotification(PlaybackStatus.PLAYING);
        }

        @Override
        public void onSkipToPrevious() {
            super.onSkipToPrevious();
            skipToPrevious();
            updateMetaData();
            buildNotification(PlaybackStatus.PLAYING);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStop() {
            super.onStop();
            removeNotification();
            //Stop the service
            stopSelf();
        }

        @Override
        public void onSeekTo(long position) {
            super.onSeekTo(position);
        }
    });
}

private void updateMetaData() {
    Bitmap                      albumArt = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.music_placeholder);
    MediaMetadataCompat.Builder builder  = new MediaMetadataCompat.Builder();
    builder.putBitmap(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM_ART, albumArt);
    builder.putString(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST, activeAudio.getArtist());
    builder.putString(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM, activeAudio.getAlbum());
    builder.putString(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_TITLE, activeAudio.getTitle());
    mediaSession.setMetadata(builder.build());
}

private void skipToNext() {
    if (audioIndex == audioList.size() - 1) {
        //if last in playlist
        audioIndex = 0;
        activeAudio = audioList.get(audioIndex);
    } else {
        //get next in playlist
        activeAudio = audioList.get(++audioIndex);
    }

    //Update stored index
    new StorageUtil(getApplicationContext()).storeAudioIndex(audioIndex);

    stopMedia();
    //reset mediaPlayer
    mediaPlayer.reset();
    initMediaPlayer();
}

private void skipToPrevious() {

    if (audioIndex == 0) {
        //if first in playlist
        //set index to the last of audioList
        audioIndex = audioList.size() - 1;
        activeAudio = audioList.get(audioIndex);
    } else {
        //get previous in playlist
        activeAudio = audioList.get(--audioIndex);
    }

    //Update stored index
    new StorageUtil(getApplicationContext()).storeAudioIndex(audioIndex);

    stopMedia();
    //reset mediaPlayer
    mediaPlayer.reset();
    initMediaPlayer();
}

private void buildNotification(PlaybackStatus playbackStatus) {
    int           pauseIcon          = R.drawable.exo_controls_pause;
    int           notificationAction = pauseIcon;
    PendingIntent play_pauseAction   = null;
    if (playbackStatus == PlaybackStatus.PLAYING) {
        notificationAction = pauseIcon;
        play_pauseAction = playbackAction(1);
    } else if (playbackStatus == PlaybackStatus.PAUSED) {
        notificationAction = R.drawable.exo_controls_play;
        play_pauseAction = playbackAction(0);
    }

    Bitmap largeIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.music_placeholder);
    // Create a new Notification

    MediaControllerCompat                             mediaControllerCompat  = mediaSession.getController();
    MediaMetadataCompat                               mediaMetadataCompat    = mediaControllerCompat.getMetadata();
    MediaDescriptionCompat                            mediaDescriptionCompat = mediaMetadataCompat.getDescription();
    android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.Builder builder                = MediaStyleHelper.from(getBaseContext(), mediaSession);
    builder.setShowWhen(false);
    builder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.MediaStyle());
    //builder.setMediaSession(mediaSession.getSessionToken());
    //builder.setShowActionsInCompactView(0, 1, 2);
    builder.setContentTitle(mediaDescriptionCompat.getTitle());
    builder.setContentText(mediaDescriptionCompat.getSubtitle());
    //builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent());
    builder.setVisibility(android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
    builder.setLargeIcon(mediaDescriptionCompat.getIconBitmap());
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon);
    builder.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
    builder.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX);
    builder.addAction(R.drawable.exo_controls_previous, "previous", playbackAction(3));
    builder.addAction(notificationAction, "pause", play_pauseAction);
    builder.addAction(R.drawable.exo_controls_next, "next", playbackAction(2));
    startForeground(453, builder.build());
}

private void removeNotification() {
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID);
}

private PendingIntent playbackAction(int actionNumber) {
    Intent playbackAction = new Intent(this, MediaPlayerService.class);
    switch (actionNumber) {
        case 0:
            // Play
            playbackAction.setAction(ACTION_PLAY);
            return PendingIntent.getService(this, actionNumber, playbackAction, 0);
        case 1:
            // Pause
            playbackAction.setAction(ACTION_PAUSE);
            return PendingIntent.getService(this, actionNumber, playbackAction, 0);
        case 2:
            // Next track
            playbackAction.setAction(ACTION_NEXT);
            return PendingIntent.getService(this, actionNumber, playbackAction, 0);
        case 3:
            // Previous track
            playbackAction.setAction(ACTION_PREVIOUS);
            return PendingIntent.getService(this, actionNumber, playbackAction, 0);
        default:
            break;
    }
    return null;
}

private void handleIncomingActions(Intent playbackAction) {
    if (playbackAction == null || playbackAction.getAction() == null) return;

    String actionString = playbackAction.getAction();
    if (actionString.equalsIgnoreCase(ACTION_PLAY)) {
        transportControls.play();
    } else if (actionString.equalsIgnoreCase(ACTION_PAUSE)) {
        transportControls.pause();
    } else if (actionString.equalsIgnoreCase(ACTION_NEXT)) {
        transportControls.skipToNext();
    } else if (actionString.equalsIgnoreCase(ACTION_PREVIOUS)) {
        transportControls.skipToPrevious();
    } else if (actionString.equalsIgnoreCase(ACTION_STOP)) {
        transportControls.stop();
    }
}
}
```

**MediaStyleHelper**

```
public class MediaStyleHelper {
    public static NotificationCompat.Builder from(Context context, MediaSessionCompat mediaSession) {
    MediaControllerCompat  controller    = mediaSession.getController();
    MediaMetadataCompat    mediaMetadata = controller.getMetadata();
    MediaDescriptionCompat description   = mediaMetadata.getDescription();

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "channel_1");
    builder.setContentTitle(description.getTitle());
    builder.setContentText(description.getSubtitle());
    builder.setSubText(description.getDescription());
    builder.setContentIntent(controller.getSessionActivity());
    builder.setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
    builder.setWhen(0);
    builder.setShowWhen(false);

    if (description.getIconBitmap() == null || description.getIconBitmap().isRecycled()) {
        builder.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.music_placeholder));
    } else {
        builder.setLargeIcon(description.getIconBitmap());
    }

    return builder;
}


public static PendingIntent getActionIntent(Context context, int mediaKeyEvent) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
    intent.setPackage(context.getPackageName());
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT, new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, mediaKeyEvent));
    return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, mediaKeyEvent, intent, 0);
}
}
```

**StorageUtil**

```
public class StorageUtil {

private final String STORAGE = " com.domain.pack.core.media.STORAGE";
private SharedPreferences preferences;
private Context           context;

public StorageUtil(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

public void storeAudio(ArrayList<Sound> arrayList) {
    preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(STORAGE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    Gson                     gson   = new Gson();
    String                   json   = gson.toJson(arrayList);
    editor.putString("audioArrayList", json);
    editor.apply();
}

public ArrayList<Sound> loadAudio() {
    preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(STORAGE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Gson   gson = new Gson();
    String json = preferences.getString("audioArrayList", null);
    Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Sound>>() {
    }.getType();
    return gson.fromJson(json, type);
}

public void storeAudioIndex(int index) {
    preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(STORAGE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.putInt("audioIndex", index);
    editor.apply();
}

public int loadAudioIndex() {
    preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(STORAGE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return preferences.getInt("audioIndex", -1);//return -1 if no data found
}

public void clearCachedAudioPlaylist() {
    preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(STORAGE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.clear();
    editor.commit();
}
}
```

//**EDIT** starting the serivice in MainActivity

```
private void playAudio(int audioIndex) {
    //Check is service is active
    if (!serviceBound) {
        //Store Serializable audioList to SharedPreferences
        StorageUtil storage = new StorageUtil(getApplicationContext());
        storage.storeAudio(audioList);
        storage.storeAudioIndex(audioIndex);

        Intent playerIntent = new Intent(this, MediaPlayerService.class);
        startService(playerIntent);
        bindService(playerIntent, serviceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    } else {
        //Store the new audioIndex to SharedPreferences
        StorageUtil storage = new StorageUtil(getApplicationContext());
        storage.storeAudioIndex(audioIndex);

        //Service is active
        //Send a broadcast to the service -> PLAY_NEW_AUDIO
        Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent(Broadcast_PLAY_NEW_AUDIO);
        sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
    }
}
```

**Service Connection**

```
//Binding this Client to the AudioPlayer Service

private ServiceConnection serviceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        // We've bound to LocalService, cast the IBinder and get LocalService instance
        MediaPlayerService.LocalBinder binder = (MediaPlayerService.LocalBinder) service;
        player = binder.getService();
        serviceBound = true;
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Service Bound", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        serviceBound = false;
    }
};
```

Comment: where do you call `startService`?

Comment: @pskink I editted the question to include starting the service.

Comment: so your `"Service stops"` means that `Service#onDestroy` is called? even if it is started (by calling `startService`) and it runs in the foreground (`startForeground` was called)?

Comment: see [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html) and ^F `Binding to a started service`

Comment: Yes, it stops even though I've called `startService` with intent, then `startForeground` with a notification. The `OnDestroy` is being called when pressing the back button.

Comment: no, its not called, see: https://pastebin.com/raw/LrX2C4Lz

Comment: and for that to work you dont even need `startForeground` to be called - it just gives the higher importance when choosing what component to kill when system needs to free some resources

Comment: I'm still trying to sort it out, but I read the docs on boundServices as you suggested, sent me the right direction. One other thing, I was stopping the service on the client.

Comment: so now, you know why `onDestroy` was called...